# 'alias this' is broken. now what?

Tags: d

I've implemented number of structs that use 'alias this' for composition, but now I'm finding out that there are bugs in the 'alias this' implementation in the language/compilers.  What are my options?  Will I have to rewrite everything?  Or do I wait till it gets fixed? and when would that be?

Comment: Probably not soon.. http://d.puremagic.com/issues/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=%22alias+this%22

Comment: If it's one or two specific problems, please detail.  There may be easy workarounds.  Generally, though, alias this is one of the buggiest features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your problem hasn't been reported yet, then please file an issue via http://d.puremagic.com/issues/enter_bug.cgi

You may also support the development by submitting patches.

Comment: I wish I could send in patches, but I have no experience with compilers.  Maybe one day.

Comment: In most cases you can also do base work: If there's an error message, find out which part of the code triggered it. If possible investigate where a change probably needs to be made like I did for http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=4419